# AppleScript and Mail.app: checking for new messages in specific account

Tags: cocoa, email, applescript

I want to include the number of new messages from a specific mail account in my zsh prompt, but I can only get mail to return the total number of new mails.

> set output_string to ""
>   tell application "Mail"
>   set Unread_Count to unread count of inbox
>   if Unread_Count is 0 then
>       set output_string to "0"
>   else
>       set output_string to ("" & (get Unread_Count))
>   end if
>   end tell
>   return Unread_Count

I've tried several other approaches like:

> set Unread_Count to unread count of account "Gmail"

but without any luck.

I would appreciate your help!
thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "Mail" to set undreadMessages to messages of mailbox "INBOX" of account "my account name" whose read status = false
```

EDIT for Marcus Rickert

```
tell application "Mail" to set Unread_Count to count (messages of mailbox "INBOX" of account "my account name" whose read status = false)
```